# Sh script to output unused interfaces on linux

Tags: sh

I asked the dark side and here's what it printed.....

```
#!/bin/bash

for interface in $(ip addr show | awk '/^[0-9]+:/ {print $2}' | tr -d :)
do
  if ! ip addr show $interface | awk '/inet / {print $2}' | grep -q . ; then
    echo $interface
  fi
done
```

I want to add n+ variable directly so the output will be the interfaces that is not used by the system,

Done

Comment: You've got a lot of interesting code there. What is the difficulty? What line of code in are you trying to *"add n+ variable directly so the output"*?  Do we really need to see all the other  code to solve that problem. Please update your question to address these issues rather than replying in comments. Good luck.

Comment: Does `a=(a b c) ; echo "${#a[@]}"` give you any ideas? Good luck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
for interface in $(ip addr show | awk '/^[0-9]+:/ {print $2}' | tr -d :)
do
  if ! ip addr show $interface | awk '/inet / {print $2}' | grep -q . ; then
    free_interfaces[$count]=$interface
    count=$((count + 1))
  fi
done

case $count in
  0)
    echo "No usable interface found."
    exit 1
    ;;
  1)
    DEFIF=${free_interfaces[0]}
    echo "The interface $DEFIF will be used."
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Available interfaces to select: "
    PS3="Press a number to select an interface to use (1-$count): "
    select interface in "${free_interfaces[@]}"; do
      DEFIF=$interface
      break
    done
    echo "The interface $DEFIF will be used."
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).